# How to make UITabBarItem be an image from unicode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can create an image with a "png" file.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Operation" 
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"] tag:0 ];
```

But I would like to use unicode image (721) or character val, ie:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Operation"
                              image: {unicode: 721 }];
```

How would I do this?  thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a little helper method that creates a small image from an `NSString` that usually contains a single Unicode character.

```
+ (UIImage *)characterImage:(NSString *)ch {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    CGSize chsize = [ch sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }];
    CGSize imgsize = CGSizeMake(16, 16);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgsize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((imgsize.width - chsize.width) / 2.0, (imgsize.height - chsize.height) / 2.0, chsize.width, chsize.height);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *pStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    pStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    pStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pStyle };
    [ch drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrs];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Adjust the font size and image size to suit your needs.

Then you can do something like this:

```
NSString *tabChar = @"✚"; // Unicode U+271A
UIImage *tabImg = [SomeHelperClass characterImage:tabChar];
```

Adjust the call to `characterImage:` based on where you add the method.